# How to show table image in cells but not in cellspacing?

Tags: html, css, image, css-tables, cellspacing

Consider a web page with a background image, pageBG.jpg.  Now consider a table with 100px x 100px cells and a relatively large cellspacing of 50px.  The table has a different background image, say, tableBG.jpg.

Is there any way to establish masking so the cells show the table's image (well, their portion of it) but the cellspacing shows the page's image?

EDIT: example image:

[image: Example]

The green is pageBG.jpb and the black/tan image is tableBG.jpg

Comment: Are your cells a fixed size, or variable?

Comment: Fixed.  See new example image above.

Answer (score 1):

You could make this work with a CSS sprite, it would just take a lot of CSS.  You'd have a page background image, and then a single image that you plan on using for the table background, but that would be used for each individual cell.  Each cell would need CSS on it to determine the x/y positioning of the image in the cell.  You'll just need to calculate the size of the cells + spacing to know where to position the image within the cells.

This would be much easier to do with DIV's I'd think.

Answer (score 0):

No, not the way you are thinking about it. I would not put the image as the cell's background image. Instead, put a `div` in the cell, size that to the proper masking size and apply the background image to that via CSS `background-image`. That `div` gets the image and the cellspacing (which appears outside the div) remains intact.

Comment: Well, it's a requirement that the image belong to the table (it's reasonably large) and the cells only show their "view" of the larger image.

Comment: Then it sounds like you are out of luck. Sorry.

Comment: I edited the original post above with an example, if that makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Thanks. That does help. Unfortunately it doesnt change my answer. The easiest way to do this is with `div`s and CSS. Doing this with a table  (while possible) is going to be difficult and problematic.

Answer (score 0):

cant you apply the class onto your table and have it apply to descendent td's?

```
table.myborderclass {
    //transparent
}

table.myborderclass td {
    background: yada
}
```

Comment: Does that make sense in light of the example image I added to the original post?